# Check if free shipping method is active programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, free-shipping

In my custom module I've created `model/carrier.php` to add custom shipping method, one of my custom shipping method will show up if magento free shipping method is not active, is there a way to do this?

**Model/carrier.php**

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
{
   $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();
   if($free_shipping_method != 'Active'){ //???
      $method->setCarrier('test');
      $method->setCarrierTitle('test');
      /* Use method name */
      $method->setMethod('test');
      $method->setMethodTitle('England is My City');
      $method->setCost('30');
      $method->setPrice('30'); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following code in your custom shipping module (carrier.php).

```
 /**
 * @var \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping
 */
protected $_freeshipping;

 public function __construct(
\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping $freeshipping
) {
        $this->_freeshipping = $freeshipping;
  }

public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active') || $this->_freeshipping->getConfigData('active')) {
            return false;
        }
 /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        $amount = $this->getShippingPrice();

        $method->setPrice($amount);
        $method->setCost($amount);

        $result->append($method);

        return $result;
}
```

Hope this answer will help you. let me know you have any further issue.
Thanks